# Get the App Version

Tags: java, android, firebase

I want to get the app version and want to compare it with the value i have added to my database . So i want to know how can i get the app version in my app . (Must be in int)

I tried this but not works :(

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int Appid;
//blah blah codes

private void GetAppID(){

try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        String version = pInfo.versionName;
        int verCode = pInfo.versionCode;
          Appid = verCode ;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is your expected value and the value you are getting?

Comment: _but not works_ Please describe your error or problem with the code

Comment: there is no error showing.

Comment: So what do you get? `null`s? 0, empty string? Some values you don't expect? What do you expect?

Comment: i want to get the app version .

Comment: Do you forget to call  `private void GetAppID()` method?

Comment: i called it in OnStart()

Comment: Could you post your LogCat through editing your question?

Comment: i am sorry to say that  test my app throw inserting apk in my moble . my emulator not works :(

Comment: BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME try to import BuildConfig specific to your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This One :D

```
 private int appversion;
        // Main activity  {

          //onCreate(){



     }

        public Void getID(){
         try {
                    PackageInfo pInfo = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
                    int verCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
                    String version = pInfo.versionName;
                    versionq = version;
                    appversion = verCode ;
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gradle you can use this code:

```
BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE
```